# Can Facebook API fb_graph retrieve my "Questoin" results Similar to retrieving feeds?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I have a facebook page. I am using fb_graph to retrieve posts on my page.

I created a question on my page. I need to retrieve my question results using fb_graph or similar ruby gem. Can I? Is this supported by facebook API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lgy answer, I have forked the fb_graph gem and added questions API support https://github.com/mahkhaled/fb_graph

Answer (score 1):

This week's [Developer blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/590/) announced the Questions API.
The documentation has been added too: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/question/

I'm not sure if it's applicable to Pages, or only to Users

Answer (score 0):

In FbGraph 2.2.1, you can fetch questions both of users and pages.

To fetch questions asked by an user,

```
user = FbGraph::User.me(ACCESS_TOKEN)
user.questions
```

To fetch questions asked by a page,

```
page = FbGraph::Page.new(PAGE_ID, :access_token => ACCESS_TOKEN)
page.questions
```